# iText converted image to pdf is too short in android

Tags: android, pdf, itext

I'm converting an image from sdcard to pdf file but unfortunately that image is not taking full length of pdf file. How I can set the image to cover all pdf file. here is my code

```
File f = new File(filePath);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Image companyLogo = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
companyLogo.setAbsolutePosition(10,700);
companyLogo.scalePercent(100);
document.add(companyLogo);
```

Can any one tell me that what should I do to cover full pdf page. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: if you scale more than its original resolution then it will fill the pdf but it will stretch and will look bad.

Comment: Its original resolution is much greater than what it is displaying :(

Comment: what is the resolution of image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File f = new File(filePath);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
Image companyLogo = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

//get size of document
Rectangle documentRect = document.getPageSize();

if(bmp.getWidth()>documentRect.getWidth() || bmp.getHeight()>documentRect.getHeight())
{
    //bitmap is larger than page,so set bitmap's size similar to the whole page 
    companyLogo.scaleAbsolute(documentRect.getWidth(), documentRect.getHeight());
}
else
{
    //bitmap is smaller than page, so add bitmap simply.[note: if you want to fill page by stretching image, you may set size similar to page as above]
    companyLogo.scaleAbsolute(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
}

//set the image with center of the page
companyLogo.setAbsolutePosition((documentRect.getWidth()-image.getScaledWidth())/2, (documentRect.getHeight()-image.getScaledHeight())/2);
```

**Note:**

To force image to cover whole page using above code,

just replace

```
if(bmp.getWidth()>documentRect.getWidth() || bmp.getHeight()>documentRect.getHeight())
{
    //bitmap is larger than page,so set bitmap's size similar to the whole page 
    companyLogo.scaleAbsolute(documentRect.getWidth(), documentRect.getHeight());
}
else
{
    //bitmap is smaller than page, so add bitmap simply.[note: if you want to fill page by stretching image, you may set size similar to page as above]
    companyLogo.scaleAbsolute(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
}
```

with

```
    companyLogo.scaleAbsolute(documentRect.getWidth(), documentRect.getHeight());
```

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: can i force the image to cover full pdf file ?

Comment: hello,i have big image with your code it gets cover in pdf but image gets stretched. do u have any solution ?